# htaccess or redirect to cloak portion of a link?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I have an ad rotate plugin installed to display a few ads on my site but the plugin is coded so that it uses the full directory in the ad count link.  I would like to know if there's something easy to put in my htacces to cloak the link.  So for example:

http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotating-plugin/rotate.php?trackerid=1

needs to look like:

http://mysite.com/rotate.php?trackerid=1  (actually any variation of this is fine, I just don't want that full wp-content/plugins/ directory shown in the link).

I've tried a few plugins but not getting the desired results.  To recap, I want the link to SHOW as the bottom link, but when clicked, be taken to the top link, and I need that trackerid=# to stay the generated id, so I only want to cloak part of the link.  Is there something I can put in my htaccess to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is set up a custom rewrite.  This can change something like `http://site.com/rotate/1` to `http://site.com/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotating-plugin/rotate.php?trackerid=1`

Here is some **untested** code that might help:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Your Plugin
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1
Author: 
Author URI: 
*/

// Add rewrite rule and flush on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ad_rotate_activate' );
function ad_rotate_activate() {
    ad_rotate_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Flush on plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'ad_rotate_deactivate' );
function ad_rotate_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Create new rewrite rule
add_action( 'init', 'ad_rotate_rewrite' );
function ad_rotate_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'rotate/([^/]+)','/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotating-plugin/rotate.php?trackerid=$matches[1]','top' );
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this to my functions.php file and it didn't seem to do anything.  Do I need to flush my permalinks?  Or does this need to be its own plugin file?

Comment: The code I wrote above was written as a plug-in ... not drop-in code for a `functions.php` file ... since you are working with a plug-in to begin with, I was making the assumption that you wanted to include the rewrite code in the plug-in.  But you need to at least do the `add_rewrite_rule()` call and then flush your rewrite rules.

Comment: @EAMann: Does this add the rule to the `rewrite_rules` item in `wp_options`? I looked at the code in `wp-includes/rewrite.php` and I'll be damned if I could say definitively one way or the other. If it *does* get saved, what prevents the rule from getting saved a whole lot of times? Enquiring minds want to know!

Comment: @Peter `add_rewrite_rule()` adds the rule to an array that's indexed based on the regular expression defined above (`rotate/([^/]+)`).  So it can't be added multiple times.  Take a look at the `add_rule()` method of the WP_Rewrite class (`/wp-includes/rewrite.php` around line 1797).

Comment: @EAMann, thanks for the clarification.  So would this work as a separate plugin, or should I put this directly in the plugin files being used?  I tried adding it as a plugin on its own and didn't get any changes to the original links.  I'm primarily a front-end designer so this stuff is a little foreign to me.  Thanks! :)

Comment: It's not meant to change any of the links.  What WordPress' url rewriter does is map requests from one url to another.  So a request to `http://site.com/rotate/1` will actually display the content from `http://site.com/wp-content/plugins/ad-rotating-plugin/rotate.php?trackerid=1`.  You also need to have pretty permalinks turned on or this is all moot.

Comment: @EAMann: So the array it's added to never gets written to the database, correct?

Comment: @EAMann, yes I have pretty permalinks turned on, but what I need to happen is the urls to be rewritten on page load, or cloaked somehow so that when the page is loaded, they don't SEE the longer link, that in fact they see the shorter link.  I'm sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: @eamann I want something similar to this. The request is redirected to rotate.php but I find `$_GET['tracker']=$matches[1]` instead of `$_GET['tracker']=1`. Did you encounter such problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Affan I'm not sure what you're asking. Please ask a new question with more detail ...