# Wordpress Redirect / Add_Rewrite_Rule - Non Index.php Page

Tags: php, redirect, htaccess

Trying to redirect visitors from `www.domain.com/abc`to `www.domain.com/company/?code=abc`,

After some research and some messing around, I am currently using the code below, which doesn't work. I flush the permalinks after each attempt.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_tag('%code%', '([^&]+)');
   add_rewrite_rule('([A-Za-z0-9]+)$', 'company/?code=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

My .htaccess page updates, and is the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /company/?code=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can anyone identify the issue?

Comment: use the full path (starting with index.php), otherwise it goes through more rewrites, or try putting it last in priority

Comment: The final landing page "/company/?code=$1" is not based on the index page. hence the use of $1 instead of $match[1]. Ill try putting it last

Comment: all wp links point to the index page in root, what we see is the pretty url

Comment: Is this still the case? See Otto's response:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27182/add-rewrite-rule-matches-var-not-replaced-by-captured-value

Comment: so you mean this page is not a WP page? the other question is about redirecting directly to a php file inside a plugin folder.

Comment: It is a WP page, a custom one. I built it using a page template

Comment: is company the page slug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `company` is the page slug try

```
'index.php?pagename=company&code=$matches[1]'
```

If you want it in .htaccess to intercept it before it goes to index.php try

```
'index.php?pagename=company&code=$1'
```

If `company` is a folder, there should be an index.php (or whatever the default file name is for your server) inside it that will process `code`.

Comment: Thank you. This works to an extent but now /cpanel doesn't work. Can this particular address be excluded?

Comment: is cpanel the only address that will ever need to be excluded? otherwise it may be safer to change it from /abc to /code/abc or /code-abc, or anything that will uniquely identify code urls.

Comment: Moved some pages to code-abc layout, just cpanel at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark as accepted :)